# Can't ssh using the URI form

Tags: ssh

I have an ssh server on my local machine and I'm trying to connect to it:

- `ssh myuser@localhost -p 8080` This works.
- `ssh ssh://myuser@localhost:8080` This doesn't.

I read that ssh allows the uri form, so why isn't it working? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) command-line utilities added the ability to specify a URI on the command line with [version 7.7](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.7):

> - ssh(1)/scp(1)/sftp(1): Add URI support to ssh, sftp and scp, e.g.
>     ssh://user@host or sftp://user@host/path.  Additional connection
>     parameters described in draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04 are not
>     implemented since the ssh fingerprint format in the draft uses the
>     deprecated MD5 hash with no way to specify the any other algorithm.

You might be using an older version of ssh which doesn't accept URIs on the command line.

Comment: You are right, my client version is `OpenSSH_7.6p1`. Thanks!